# Disable button until 2 EditText's have values

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a view with 2 `EditText` and 1 `Button`.

I need to be able to disable the button until both `EditTexts` have values (the first `EditText` is a username/email and the second is a password).

The username/email `EditText` should have a length of >= 3 and the password `EditText` should have a length of >= 6.

How can I disable the button until these restrictions are met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TextWatcher on each EditText

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    ...
    @Overide
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(username.getText().length >= 3 && pwd.getText().length >= 6)
            btn.setEnabled(true)
        else
            btn.setEnabled(false)
    }
}

username.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
pwd.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```